# Angular 2+ formgroup setValue in child component form from parent

Tags: forms, angular

I have a form component that I want to share between an add member component and an edit member component.  Everything works fine if I put the form code in each component but, well, I don't want to be banned from coding forever because my code isn't DRY.  I'm new at coding.

The problem to be solved is this message in my IDE, Webstorm:

> Property 'setValue' does not exist on type 'AddEditFormComponent'.

This message comes from the parent component EditMemberComponent.  First I'll present the form code that I'm trying to share between the edit and add components.

This is the child component, the basic form:

add-edit-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-add-edit-form',
templateUrl: './add-edit-form.component.html'
})

export class AddEditFormComponent implements OnInit {

  addEditMemberForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.addEditMemberForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      mainSkillTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      mainSkills: ['', Validators.required],
      otherSkills: ['', Validators.required],
      links: ['', Validators.required],
      country: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

With a little Angular Material 2 styling the form looks good.

This is the problem parent component:

edit-member.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MembersAdminService } from './member-admin.service';
import { Member } from './member-admin.model';
import { AddEditFormComponent } from './add-edit-form.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-member',
  templateUrl: './edit-member.component.html'
})

export class EditMemberComponent implements OnInit {

  private memberId: string;
  private memberData;
  private addEditMemberForm: AddEditFormComponent;

  constructor(
      private membersAdminService: MembersAdminService,
      private successService: SuccessService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchMember();
  }

  fetchMember() {
    this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
      this.memberId = urlParameters['id'];
      console.log(this.memberId); // Perfect
    });

    // Display the data retrieved from the data model to the form model.
   this.membersAdminService.getMemberById(this.memberId)
      .subscribe(dataLastEmittedFromObserver => {
          this.memberData = dataLastEmittedFromObserver;
          console.log(this.memberData);  // This works fine.  Now to post to form...

          this.addEditMemberForm.setValue({ // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            firstName: this.memberData.firstName,
            lastName: this.memberData.lastName,
            mainSkillTitle: this.memberData.mainSkillTitle,
            mainSkills: this.memberData.mainSkills,
            otherSkills: this.memberData.otherSkills,
            links: this.memberData.links,
            country: this.memberData.country
          })
      });
   }

}
```

I expected this line to bring all the form code into the parent:

```
private addEditMemberForm: AddEditFormComponent;
```

Along with this import I expected .setValue to be available in the parent to the addEditMemberForm property. I expected setValue to populate the child form with the member data so I can edit it.  That isn't happening and I suspect I have an incomplete mental map of how this works.

Help is appreciated of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get hold of `AddEditFormComponent` i would use `@ViewChild`

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

...
@ViewChild(AddEditFormComponent)
private addEditMemberComponent: AddEditFormComponent;
```

and then we can write

```
this.addEditMemberComponent.addEditMemberForm.setValue({ // THIS SHOULD WORK
  ...
```

Comment: yurzui, this solution worked once. After entering your code the app rebuilt and the member data was in the form.  This member was already selected before the refresh.  When I went back to the list of members and selected the same member to see his detail then the form crashed.  By "crashed" I mean the fields are visible but no css and no data.  And I get that error message again: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined at SafeSubscriber.membersAdminService.getMemberById.subscribe.dataLastEmittedFromObserver [as _next] (edit-member.component.ts:87). However, the app compiles.

Comment: I think your solution is correct but it reveals another problem.  The app is sending the Firebase $key / memberId to the URL but the key is instantly deleted in the URL.  I an see the key for less than a second.  I'm trying to figure this out.  This isn't a problem when the form component code is in the AddEditMemberComponent.   I didn't realize that being DRY is so much trouble :-)

Comment: .subscribe(dataLastEmittedFromObserver => {
          this.memberData = dataLastEmittedFromObserver;
          console.log(this.memberId);  // The memberId is here. Next line of code crashes the form. It won't setValue.

          this.addEditMemberComponent.addEditMemberForm.setValue({
            ...

Comment: The data object exists before the setValue.  The setValue is crashing the form.

Comment: This is in my parent html:  <app-add-edit-form #addEditMemberForm></app-add-edit-form>.  Maybe something wrong here.

Comment: Please create plunker to reproduce it

Comment: yurzui, you just asked me to engineer a moon landing :-)  This code is deep inside my app.  I think to create a useful plunker I would have to build a new app. I use Firebase for the sample data and not sure that would work with plunker.  That would take me hours.  Is that how plunker works?  You would have to see a working app, right?

Comment: I suspect that my form is the problem. The data isn't binding to it when it is separated into its own component.  What worked when they are together doesn't now.  It should be something like <app-add-edit-form [something]=something></app-add-edit-form>.  So far everything I've tried failed.

Answer (score 0):

yurzui's response is very good and helped me go in the right direction.  There are a variety of ways of getting data in and out of forms and for my app the @ViewChild is the best option.

However, I still couldn't get data into the form and it was crashing when I tried.  My comments above reflect that struggle.

The final part of the answer is that I can not use ngOnInit() in the parent class.  I must use this life cycle hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.fetchMember();
}
```

This issue is that the form needed time to render before trying to load data.  Dah!  :-)  Hope all this helps some other lost puppy.  The other issue is that I'm going to have to figure out how to use Plunker someday. So much to learn on my first app!